# Cross-subdomain Admin login with login sharing

Tags: django, django-admin, subdomain

I have a sites with two subdomains

- www.example.com
- test.example.com

Both talk to same DB. However both are separate code bases.

I want a Admin login to persist between the two sites. (If you
are logged in to www, you are automatically logged in to test and vice versa)

I have these settings in `settings.py`

```
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".example.com"
SECRET_KEY ="theeisnospoonblahblah"
```

The Admins seems to be talking, but in a weird way.

If I go to www.example.com and am logged into Admin, if I go to test.example.com, instead of being logged in to test.example.com admin,

I am automatically logged out of www.example.com .

Am I missing a settings in `settings.py`

Comment: The sites www and test are on Django versions on 1.3 beta 1, and 1.2.5.

Comment: The CSRF and sessionid cookies are domain specific, they will be set for each domain as in foo.bar.com and www.bar.com will have different cookies. My django isn't good, but you will need to see where the cookie is defined and make the domain bar.com that will work for foo and www.bar.com then